# The quality of images became worse after adding to resource

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

By default the quality of image is fine, but when I load it to the resource the quality became blurred. Why it's happening and how to fix it?

example whith original image and how it look's on page

[image]

```
// S L I D E R - S I N G L E
function setCurrent (first){
$('.current').html(first);
}
// set images to preview and remove big images
$('.description-single').find('img').each(function(){  
  var photoSrc  = $(this).attr('src'),
      photoImg  = '<img src="' + photoSrc + '">';
  $('.all-photos').append('<div class="photo-template">' + photoImg + '</div>');
  $(this).remove();
}); // end each
// set first image preview to current box 
var firstPhoto = $('.all-photos').find('div.photo-template:first').html()
setCurrent(firstPhoto);
// click handler
$('div.photo-template').on('click', function(){
  var selected = $(this).html();
  setCurrent(selected);
});
if($('.all-photos .photo-template img').length < 2) {
  $('.all-photos').hide();
}
```

live example http://beardhouse.com.ua/detskie-divany/mishutka

Comment: Are you changing its size?

Comment: no, perhapse the bootstrap guilty in it...

Comment: By changing in size, I also mean the web page may be rescaling it.  Unless the picture is exactly the same number of pixels as the original, you're not going to get full fidelity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is a problem with how bootstrap has the img tag in CSS has a max-width: 100%; The container box is smaller than the image so it's downsizing and losing quality.

Looking at the CSS it looks like the padding on .current is messing up the sizing of the actual image.

Comment: I add the img to the page whithout any thumbnail sizing or something else. There is a script which get all img on page and put them to the gallery.
There is no scale in main block whith picture. The main img has the original sizes.

Comment: nice function but it but it did not help me

Comment: Yeah this is most likely a problem with bootstrap then. I would ask for a link so I could see the CSS.

Comment: tnx, it was bootsrap!
the padding inside main div - сreated this evil!